# failed cross compiling aws webrtc library

Tags: c, linux, amazon-web-services, embedded, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile aws webrtc library(https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c) for arm. So I followed the instruction on Readme.md but I failed.

What I did

```
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
export CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
cmake .. -DBUILD_TEST=TRUE -DBUILD_OPENSSL=TRUE -DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=TRUE -DBUILD_OPENSSL_PLATFORM=linux-generic32 -DBUILD_LIBSRTP_HOST_PLATFORM=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -DBUILD_LIBSRTP_DESTINATION_PLATFORM=arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi
```

The error I encountered

```
Scanning dependencies of target kvsCommonLws
[ 26%] Building C object CMakeFiles/kvsCommonLws.dir/src/source/Common/Auth.c.o
In file included from /home/jacob/Workspace/Github/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c/open-source/libkvsCommonLws/build/src/libkvsCommonLws-download/src/source/Common/Include_i.h:41,
                 from /home/jacob/Workspace/Github/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c/open-source/libkvsCommonLws/build/src/libkvsCommonLws-download/src/source/Common/Auth.c:5:
/home/jacob/Workspace/Github/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c/open-source/include/libwebsockets.h:120:10: fatal error: sys/capability.h: No such file or directory
  120 | #include <sys/capability.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/kvsCommonLws.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/kvsCommonLws.dir/src/source/Common/Auth.c.o' failed
make[5]: *** [CMakeFiles/kvsCommonLws.dir/src/source/Common/Auth.c.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/kvsCommonLws.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/kvsCommonLws.dir/all' failed
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
CMakeFiles/libkvsCommonLws-download.dir/build.make:111: recipe for target 'build/src/libkvsCommonLws-download-stamp/libkvsCommonLws-download-build' failed
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [build/src/libkvsCommonLws-download-stamp/libkvsCommonLws-download-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/libkvsCommonLws-download.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/libkvsCommonLws-download.dir/all' failed
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
CMake Error at CMake/Utilities.cmake:65 (message):
  CMake step for libkvsCommonLws failed: 2
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:150 (build_dependency)
```

Comment: Each of this packages has this header (Debian): libcap-dev,libklibc-dev,dietlibc-dev (I don't know, which the right one is)

Comment: @JCWasmx86 I installed all of it but it is the same. Should I cross compile libcap-dev for arm too?

Comment: You should have all of them installed as cross-compiled binaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with your ARM toolchain or how the build system uses it. Where did you get it from and how did you install it?

The header `sys/capability.h` is included with the ARM toolchain. For example, when I install the Debian package `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` then this header file gets copied to `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/linux/capability.h`. The toolchain is supposed to find it there on its own.

The command `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -v` will show you where the toolchain is configured to look for its own header files. E.g. in output below it's `--includedir=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include` that matters, the header should be found relative to this directory. I apologize for the super long line.

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 10.2.1-1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-10/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-10 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --without-target-system-zlib --enable-multiarch --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv7-a --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 --with-float=hard --with-mode=thumb --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf- --includedir=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-mutex
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.2.1 20201207 (Debian 10.2.1-1)
```

You can also try increasing the verbosity of your cmake build process to verify that it's calling the right cross compiler. I've forgotten the details, but perhaps adding a flag `-v` will help.

Comment: I checked it but there is no the option(--includedir=). Is it possible to add the option? I cross compiled libcap-dev with the toolchain.

Comment: Your toolchain seems to be broken. What system are you on, where did you get the compiler from?

Comment: It is not common toolchain. It is from some PCB company.

Comment: Then you're at their mercy :) Anyway, most popular ARM gcc toolchains come from ARM, linaro or your distribution (Debian/Ubuntu?) - perhaps you can switch to one of those.

Comment: I tried these toolchains:
gcc-arm-8.2-2018.08-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz, 
gcc-arm-8.2-2019.01-x86_64-arm-eabi.tar.xz, 
gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz,

Comment: But they make the same error so I put capability.h to include/sys/ and added "typedef int cap_value_t;" in capability.h. After that, I succeeded cmake. But there is another issue on make command. It returns this error: location R_ARM_THM_MOVW_ABS_NC against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
../open-source/lib/libsrtp2.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I also have this error: arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/jacob/Workspace/Github/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c/open-source/lib/libwebsockets.a: error adding symbols: file format not recognized

Comment: Double-check the target platforms you give cmake for libsrtp library. Are you sure `arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi` is correct? You need to have matching toolchain and libraries installed.

Comment: How can I know my target platform's name?

Comment: See this presentation, slide 5: https://elinux.org/images/1/15/Anatomy_of_Cross-Compilation_Toolchains.pdf
Usually your toolchain's name corresponds to your platform. If you've chosen "arm-linux-gnueabihf" correctly, then that's the platform.

Comment: I tried arm-linux-gnueabihf but it is the same XD

Comment: I think I should cross compile all libraries in "amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c/open-source/lib"

Comment: Certainly, as the x86 binaries definitely won't help you on an arm platform. Looking at the readme file I would have assumed that the project's Makefile takes care of all that, but I guess you'd have to look at what they're actually doing in there